# Touch events not working on ios build of cordova app

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ios10, cordova-ios

I have a very simple cordova app that is an extension of the default cordova 'device ready' template. It has one button with a simple click event attached.

as can be seen here running on an iOS simulator.

[image: Simple Cordova app]

The following is the code of my project

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Simple App</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="testBttn">Press me</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {
       app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

app.initialize();

console.log('ready to test button');

document.getElementById("testBttn").addEventListener("click", function (){
  console.log('button was pressed!');
});
```

The problem I am facing is that the button is completely unresponsive to any click (touch gesture) when running on the simulator

**The button works fine and outputs to console when run in a browser**

When I run the app through XCode on the simulator instead of the CLI I get the same result although I get the following output as soon as I click *anywhere* on the simulator screen.

```
2016-10-13 00:16:57.738602 CordovaApp[14845:2773283] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: Touch, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-13 00:16:57.739331 CordovaApp[14845:2773283] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: Gesture, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-13 00:16:57.741806 CordovaApp[14845:2773283] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: GestureExclusion, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
```

This output offers little insight but may indicate an obvious issue. I have never had this output when building native ios applications.

Any help appreciated.

**Edit:** I am using XCode 8.0

I mention this as it appears this kind of console output is quite common in XCode 8 when building ios 10 apps. It seems from what I can find that this console output is trivial and is nothing out of the ordinary..

Comment: please write document.getElementById("testBttn").addEventListener("click", function (){
  console.log('button was pressed!');
}); 

in receiverEvent function

Comment: if you start cross platform please http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/ it's have better manner code for it and also using cordova.

Comment: By adding the event listener to the receivedEvent function like you suggested unfortunately does not produce any different result :(

Answer (score 2):

I have found the same thing happening to me today all of a sudden. The only solution that I have found isn't really a solution at all but when I switch to a different app and then switch back to my app suddenly the touch events all start working again. But a freshly opened app is completely unresponsive. So not exactly a solution but see if you experience the same behaviour.

Comment: Just hearing that someone else has this problem and its reproducible is music to my ears. At least it is an issue that goes beyond any fault of ours and an answer in this thread may help anyone in future solve their same issue

Comment: Actually I provided a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using `touchstart` should work:

```
initialize: function() {
    document.getElementById('testBtn').addEventListener('touchstart', this.clickedBtn.bind(this), false);
},

clickedBtn: function() {
    console.log('CLICKED THE BUTTON!');
},
```