# WkWebView Cordova Ios onClick events not firing

Tags: ios, cordova, wkwebview

I've been chasing my own tail for hours. I've read same issue [here](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/1175) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39997354/touch-events-not-working-on-ios-build-of-cordova-app#39998450)

My Cordova app is basically unresponsive to click events using the ios iphone simulator on my mac. It's also unresponsive in an iphone. Works fine in the browser when doing `cordova run browser`. I need to mention, yes, everything is inside `deviceready` so that is not the issue. The only things that are working are `href`. Everything else is unresponsive. What is the solution?

**html**

```
<button id="pressOn">press me</button>
```

I tried :

**This**

```
$("#pressOn").on("touchend", openPage('login'));
```

**This**

```
$("#pressOn").on("touchstart", openPage('login'));
```

**This**

```
let touchEvent = 'ontouchstart' in window ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
$('#pressOn').on(touchEvent, openPage('login'));
```

None works... Nothing happens.

However somehow this fires when the app appears on the simulator (without me doing/touching anything)

```
document.getElementById('pressOn').addEventListener('touchstart', alert('cheer up!'), false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how event listeners work. Actually, you need a function as the second parameter, not a function call:

```
$(selector).on( eventname , functionDef )
```

In your case you can do it this way:

```
$("#pressOn").on("touchend", function () { openPage('login') });

$("#pressOn").on("touchstart", function () { openPage('login') });

let touchEvent = 'ontouchstart' in window ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
$('#pressOn').on(touchEvent, function () { openPage('login') });
```

If you use a function call like `openPage('login')` this will be parsed and executed instantly and not in the event flow. For this same reason your call is firing the alert immediately:

```
document.getElementById('pressOn').addEventListener('touchstart', alert('cheer up!'), false);
```

You need to use a function closure to define the event listener, like this:

```
document.getElementById('pressOn').addEventListener('touchstart', function() { alert('cheer up!') }, false);
```